# Inserting array data into database on play framework anorm

Tags: sql, arrays, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I need to store array data into database. But I don't find samples how to do that. I tried just treating array as a normal data type but it seems it doesn't work. Here is my code:

In the database table, I have 3 columns:

```
Id integer,
uLocation integer,
Prices integer(366)
```

In SQL, insert, update or query the table by using:

```
def InseartToDatabase(ItemPrices: ListBuffer[Int], Id: Int, uLocation: Int) = {
     val prices = ItemPrices.toArray
     DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
         SQL("insert into task (Id, uLocation, Prices) values ({Id},{uLocation}, {Prices})").on('Id ->Id, 'uLocation->uLocation, 'Prices -> Prices).executeUpdate()
     }
}
```

This doesn't work just silently and no exception reported. But next update just failed. If I remove the array fields, above code just works fine.

Also, I have no idea how to query it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using H2, try to use Postgresql mode. Postgresql supports Array data type [(ref)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html) and starts from playframework 2.4.x, Anorm supports array column parser [(ref)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm), you can query it like:

```
import anorm.SQL
import anorm.SqlParser.{ scalar, * }

// array and element parser
import anorm.Column.{ columnToArray, stringToArray }

val res: List[Array[String]] =
SQL("SELECT str_arr FROM tbl").as(scalar[Array[String]].*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database you are using. Not all databases support array data types. I stand to be corrected but don't think anorm supports arrays in the way you are expecting. There is some discussion and a potential workaround on [this google group's thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/qs7mbWwIjjY).

P.S. Allow me to make a plug for a separate table for your multi-valued column. For a relatively small inconvenience, you get standard sql processing (easier to maintain) and better cross-platform code, to name a few benefits. :)

Comment: I am using H2 in memory. I now converted the array into blob and it seems working. However, I don't know how to query it out. I am using {SQL("select Id, Prices from task").as(int("Id") ~ blob("Prices")  map(flatten) *) }, but the compiler complains blob is not found.

Comment: Have you seen the [anorm page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm)? There's an image file/binary there. But what about a simpler approach, store it in a string, using mkString and split? (or a separate table ;) )

Answer (score 0):

use .toSeq, instead list, this might work.

```
SQL("insert into task (Id, uLocation, Prices) values ({Id},{uLocation}, {Prices})").on('Id ->Id, 'uLocation->uLocation.toSeq, 'Prices -> Prices).executeUpdate()
```